# Control a function evaluation context

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, eval, evaluation

I provide my users an opportunity to define a custom function `f`, whose
execution depends on various custom parameters `parms` which they choose.

- It is their responsibility to ensure that every parameter they need have been
  defined for the function to be evaluated.
- It is my responsibility to run this function.

An nasty solution is to make them write their custom code as a string, then to
replace their variable names with the parameters they need, like in:

```
## User side
parms = {'a': 5,
         'b': 89,
         'c': 'third_user_parameter'}
f=\
"""# any operation, user is free:
if len(c) > 10:
    result = sum(ord(char) for char in c)
else:
    result = a + b
"""

## My side
exec(f, parms, parms)
result = parms['result']
print(result)
```

The main problem with this approach (apart from the fact that `result` must be
reserved as a keyword) is that user must define her procedure in a string, which
is quite not convenient.

Is there a way I could allow users define an actual *function* and then make use of
it?
How could I evaluate their function with their parameters as variables whenever
I need it ?

In a nutshell, I wish this could work, but it does not:

```
## User side
parms = {'a': 5,
         'b': 89,
         'c': 'third_user_parameter'}
def f():
    if len(c) > 10:
        return sum(ord(char) for char in c)
    else:
        return a + b


## My side
eval('f()', parms, parms) # NameError: name 'f' is not defined
parms.update({'f': f})
eval('f()', parms, parms) # NameError: name 'c' is not defined
exec('f()', parms, parms) # NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Without changing the user side, is there a way I could execute `f()` within the
"context" of `parms` and get the expected result?

Comment: `f.__globals__.update(parms)` and call it as `f()` (no need for `eval`).

Comment: This is it. Perfect, thanks :) Does this not deserve an answer?

Comment: Frankly, this isn't a very nice solution as it updates the global namespace of the module in which the function is defined. I'm sure there're better solutions

Comment: It would be a lot better if you could make your users write the function in such a way that it accepts the parameters as formal parameters in the function signature. It's really ugly to rely on some magic injection of bindings that would not be the case had they used the same function in a normal Python environment.

Comment: @vaultah I understand. It should be my responsibility to ensure that user-defined parameters will not override anything important, but it sure will be difficult to control everything. Is there a python-neat way to protect module identifiers?

Comment: @blubberdiblub Do you mean that they should `def f(a, b, c)` in addition to `parms = {'a': .., 'b': .., 'c': ..}` ? It sure looks better, but it will become unconvenient to maintain when `parms` gets big or variable. Is there no neat way to factorize user's parameter list?

Comment: @iago-lito well, if there's only ever exactly one function, you could generate the function header automatically and the user only writes the function body.

Comment: @blubberdiblub then, she will have to write it in a string, right? ^ ^ Are we back to the start?

Comment: @iago-lito I'm not really sure what you mean by "write it in a string"? I don't know if you give them a form to input their code or let them provide a full script file. Either you provide a restricted environment where they are only allowed to do certain things (i. e. provide a number of parameters and the body of a function) or you provide a free environment where they can do everything they please, such as write multiple functions or write no functions at all, and where they can also be expected to provide the correct signature and formal parameters to a function.

Comment: @blubberdiblub I understand their situation is not clear. My profound intent here is to dissociate the *programmatic expression* they will write (or "function body" or "piece of code" or "functional form") from the *parameters* it will use. Parameters will change, functional form will stay the same. BTW this is what *functions* are meant to do, right? I am using `def f():` because it is the best *programmatic expression wrapper* I know in python.. But functions come with the burden of predefined "signature", which I wish to factor away. *ie.* I need a kind of "proto-function", does that exist?

Comment: @iago-lito I really don't like the notion of the function signature being a burden. It clearly defines which parameters a function accepts and in which order. And if they are named in a clear way, you can even discern their purpose. By reading the function definition alone, you should be able to discern what the inputs to the function are (which, ideally, should only be parameters, not globals or injected values).

Comment: @blubberdiblub Haha! Of course ^ ^ It sure is **not** a burden for me as a *developer*. I like the signature providing me readability, security, discipline, evolvability etc. I meant it is a burden for my *users*. In an ideal world, all they would need to do is to define, say, `def user_expression(x): return a + x if x > b else x - c`, then provide every parameters this expression needs with `parms = parameters(a=5, b=8, c=9)`, then it would be my job to `evaluate(user_expression, x=42, parms)`.. can you see what I am looking for? Maybe I should reformulate OP.

Comment: @iago-lito Yeah, I've been thinking about what your actual goal is, as I'm really disturbed by now (you see, I believe in the value of teaching good Python). So it appears like your users aren't in a Python context at all. It's more like you're teaching them mathematics or algorithms and you're just using Python as an easily available tool to have a platform for their input. While I can see some short-term practical merits to your approach, to me it feels like an abuse of Python and a way to teach bad programming techniques to students who'll happen to venture into the Python world later.

Comment: @blubberdiblub You're totally right: 1) users are not in a Python context but I use Python as an input platform 2) this is bad Python teaching. However, what I am realizing now is that: there *is* a conceptual difference between function "variables" (`x` in my example), and function "parameters" (`a, b, c` in my example), even though machines do not make such a difference at low-level. Is there no high-level reification of such a concept in Python language? If not, maybe using `f.__globals__.update(parms)` magic is my best, hackish workaround. I'll be clear and set warnings in the doc ;)

Comment: Well, there's `inner_func.__closure__` for nested functions, which doesn't touch globals. But I don't know whether you can inject that for top-level functions, which don't have that attribute by default, or whether you can even create cell-type objects yourself for use in that attribute.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Cheers. I'm having a look into this. Do you have good pointers to get into `__globals__`, `__closure__` magic, and the internals of python evaluation procedures? :)

Comment: According to the [documentation for Cells](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/cell.html) they are not going to be useful, even if you'd be able to create them yourself, as the bytecode of your function will not have been compiled in such a way as to dereference them in the first place. `__globals__` should just be a dict, albeit the attribute appears to be read-only. (i. e. you will likely not be able to replace it with a completely separate dict)

Comment: @blubberdiblub yupe. Editing `__globals__` does work anyway. I'll just be careful and raise exceptions if `update`ing it should override existing entries. Users will just have to pick different names then, I guess. And I will clean after use! Thank you for your deep insight into my questionning and for this interesting chat :) I'll keep you updated if I find neater ways to proceed.

Comment: @blubberdiblub much better python-highjacking: I'll use magic in order to infer `parms` from function's **kwargs**. *i.e.* user will only have to write `def f(x, a=5, b=42, c=12): ...` and I'll inferm `parms` myself. No more messing around with `globals`!

Comment: @iago-lito well, that's really nice, but didn't you want to avoid putting parameters into the function signature?

Comment: @blubberdiblub what I want to avoid is user having to define them *twice*. Here user defines parameters once only, and I still can discriminate them from variables and manipulate them independently. Here we go! In other words, I am just highjacking the *semantics* of python kwargs feature.. let's hope it'll be enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to [blubberdiblub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794539/blubberdiblub) comments, it turns out that I mostly need to separate user's expression *variables* from their *parameters*, without users needing to define their parameters twice.

One dirty solution is to highjack `f` execution context with `f.__globals__.update(parms)`, but this is really bad python as it messes up with `globals()`.

The solution I like best is to use python's **kwargs** feature to discriminate between variable and parameters. This is also a dirty highjack, it also uses magic, but still we are [toying with less powerful forces](https://xkcd.com/419/):

```
## User side
def user_expression(x,
        # parameters
        a=5,
        b=89,
        c='third_user_parameter'
        ):
    if len(c) > 10:
        intermediate = sum(ord(char) for char in c)
        return x + intermediate
    else:
        return x - b

## My side;
# extract parameters, encoded as kwargs:
values = user_expression.__defaults__
nb_kwargs = len(values)
nb_args = user_expression.__code__.co_argcount
names = user_expression.__code__.co_varnames[nb_args - nb_kwargs:nb_args]
parms = {k: v for k, v in zip(names, values)}
# evaluate the expression with these parameters or other ones:
result = user_expression(42, **parms)
print(result)
```